# Add Applet in project

Tags: java, html, applet

I understood from people my error and thanx for them. I have to add and extends Applet file to my ready project. Should I start from begining or it is possible just add Applet to the project and make it work? I have to add my programm to HTML.

Here is pictures of my error and my project:
[Jar file and puctures](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/scl3fgewg94tbgb/AACkMXLsea-wNVvFQWYjFgTEa?dl=0)

Comment: Don't ;post (links to) pictures of textual information, copy/paste the ***text!***  As to the problem, an applet must `extends Applet` or `extends JApplet` when your class obviously doesn't.

Comment: BTW - is this Swing as suggested by the tag, or Java-FX as suggested by the fxml tag?

Comment: Or JApplet, or whatever the JavaFX equivalent is, if any.

Answer (score 1):

`hht_7.HHT_7` needs to `extends` `Applet`

Comment: That answer implies to me that it **cannot** `extends JApplet` (which is wrong).